# React navigation, route data is throwing "undefined is not an object"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Trying to pass data into the second page of an application using react-navigation routes but the item data doesn't seem to be getting transferred correctly. Pretty new to React nav to wouldn't doubt if it's something simple. Here's the code.

the sending of the data:

```
<FlatList
                        data={posts}
                        renderItem={(item) =>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={(item) => navigation.navigate("DiscoverDetails", { item })} style={styles.card}>
                                {/*top row */}
                                <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                                    {/*this changes depending on the filter, make icon a var */}
                                    <View style={styles.cardIconBox}></View>
                                    {/* title and tag container */}
                                    <View style={styles.cardTitleContainer}>
                                        <Text style={styles.cardTitleStyle}>{item.item.title}</Text>
                                        <Text>{item.item.tags}</Text>

                                    </View>
                                </View>
                                {/*bottom row */}
                                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                                    <View style={styles.cardHorDivide} />
                                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                                        {/*this is the horizontal divs on the bottom */}
                                        <View style={styles.cardBotChunk}>
                                            <Image style={styles.clock} source={require('../assets/clock.png')} />
                                            <Text style={styles.intStyle}>{item.item.length}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                        <View style={styles.vertDiv} />
                                        <View style={styles.cardBotChunk}>
                                            <Image style={styles.clock} source={require('../assets/user.png')} />
                                            <Text style={styles.intStyle}>344</Text>
                                        </View>
                                        <View style={styles.vertDiv} />
                                        <View style={styles.cardBotChunk}>
                                            <Image style={styles.clock} source={require('../assets/start-black.png')} />
                                            <Text style={styles.intStyle}>14</Text>
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        }
                    />
```

the destination:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const DiscoverDetails = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    const { item } = route.params;
    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <Text>{item.item.title}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default DiscoverDetails;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }
})
```

Also, I'm aware of the dumb item.item situation that I have going on here. The firebase data is nested kinda weird or something so this was the only way to get the data to show. Not sure if that's the source of the issue or not but I have tried both item.title and item.item.title and both still produce the error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check the contents of route.params?

Comment: route[object Object] is what is printed out.

Comment: use a JSON.stringify(route.params) and see whats getting passed, then easy for your to debug

Comment: just getting empty brackets as is nothing is getting passed through? As far as I can tell the route code is fine it's just something wrong with item. Might be something to do with the fact that its coming from firebase query?

Comment: Check my answer,it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the problem,

Here you pass the item from the onPress instead of the item that you get from render.

So change this

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={(item) => navigation.navigate("DiscoverDetails", { item })} style={styles.card}>
```

To (Remove the parameter item)

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("DiscoverDetails", { item })} style={styles.card}>
```

Comment: oops, simple mistake. Thanks for the help!